# Error in sending configuration MSG to ARS308 Radar sensor through CANcaseXL

Tags: vb.net, can-bus

I'm working on a research that includes sending and reviving CAN msgs from ARS308 radar sensor through the CANcaseXL ,, I was able to write a VB.net code that can send this configuration msg using ID 0x200 ,, but out of sudden the radar just stop responding to the msg although I was monitoring and able to check that the data was transmitted from the PC through the CANcaseXL to the Radar.
Moreover I'm receiving now strange msgs IDs from the Radar like these IDs: 0x478 , 0x271 that doesn't mentioned in the manual of the ARS308 radar sensor, so I don't know what is the data in them.

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you checked error count on CANalyzer? Plus is this repeatative behaviour? I mean, On start up, Radar responds and then suddenly stops?

Comment: Actually I figured out what was the problem ,, somehow my code send some configuration data to sensor ID number 7 ,, and the default sensor ID is 0 ,, so I just sent a default stetting in my case to ID:270 to let radar sensor ID go back to zero and it works!
but thanks for your comment :)